# jQuery Dynamic Function Calls Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dynamic

I'm able to use jQuery easytabs library perfectly on normal situation, but when I'm creating dynamic easytabs, it is not working anymore. I think they are not initialized. Here is my code. I'm trying to initialize each div that have id="tab" prefix. But this doesn't work.

```
<script src="../js/JSPkg/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="../js/JSPkg/jquery.hashchange.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/JSPkg/jquery.easytabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div[id^="tab"]').easytabs();
} );
</script>
```

I have PHP code that loops on this Div for easytabs:

```
echo"<div id='tab2-container". $row ['ID']."' class='tab2-container'>
<ul class='etabs2'>
<li class='tab2'><a href='#tab1-". $row['ID'] ."'>Tab1</a></li>
<li class='tab2'><a href='#tab2-". $row['ID'] ."'>Tab2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class='panel2-container'>
<div id='tab1-". $row ['ID'] ."'> TestData1";

echo "</div>
<div id='tab2-". $row['ID'] ."'> TestData2 ";

echo "</div>
</div>
</div> ";
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this may be css is the problem.do not use jquery version more than 1.7:change js file path as per yours.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-hashchange/v1.3/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.easytabs/3.2.0/jquery.easytabs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
    /* Example Styles for Demo */
    .etabs2 { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    .tab2 { display: inline-block; zoom:1; *display:inline; background: #eee; border: solid 1px #999; border-bottom: none; -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; }
    .tab2 a { font-size: 14px; line-height: 2em; display: block; padding: 0 10px; outline: none; }
    .tab2 a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
    .tab2.active { background: #fff; padding-top: 6px; position: relative; top: 1px; border-color: #666; }
    .tab2 a.active { font-weight: bold; }
    .tab2-container .panel2-container { background: #fff; border: solid #666 1px; padding: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px; }
    .panel2-container { margin-bottom: 10px; }
  </style>
<?php 
$row ['ID']="xyz";//temporary value taken
echo"<div id='tab2-container". $row ['ID']."' class='tab2-container'>
<ul class='etabs2'>
<li class='tab2'><a href='#tab1-". $row['ID'] ."'>Tab1</a></li>
<li class='tab2'><a href='#tab2-". $row['ID'] ."'>Tab2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class='panel2-container'>
<div id='tab1-". $row ['ID'] ."'> TestData1";

echo "</div>
<div id='tab2-". $row['ID'] ."'> TestData2 ";

echo "</div></div></div> ";

?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[id^="tab"]').easytabs();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Suchit, thanks for the answer but I tried it already but didn't work for it. When I change it to say change div color, it is working, but on this one it doesn't. Thanks.

Comment: @Jemru see the demo i have added.

Comment: I changed your code to add another tab, because this is my real scenario issue. The second tab doesn't work. thank you.